# What is the problem with my Excel file that I can not read in to it?

Tags: openpyxl, excel-2016, python-3.9

I am using python with the openpyxl library and want to read in an Excel file as follows:

```
import openpyxl

input_file = openpyxl.load_workboork(r"C:\Something...\input.xlsx", data_only=True)
input_sheet = input_file["Sheet01"]
```

I used `data_only=True` to include date and time formats in addition to standard formats in Excel

My Excel version is from 2016.

After running the code, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Something...\main.py", line 2, in <module> input_file = openpyxl.load_workboork(r"C:\Something...\input.xlsx", data_only=True)
File "C:\Something...\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 346, in load_workbook
reader.read()
File "C:\Something...\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 307, in read
raise ValueError(ValueError: Unable to read workbook: could not read worksheets from C:\Something...\input.xlsx
This is most probably because the workbook source files contain some invalid XML.
```

1. My openpyxl library is up to date as far as I know.
2. In the file I have already removed all used filters  and unwanted
   formats.
3. I opened and repaired my file, and saved it again.
4. My file is insanely large with about 2800 lines and 52 columns.
5. I don't have formats other than the standard text and number
   formats, and date and time formats in my file.
6. I have also used pandas but the error is also here when reading the
   file. The error message is very similar as far as I know.

I think that either there is still something wrong with the file or the problem is with the library however as mentioned it doesn't work with `Pandas` either. 

Otherwise I am completely stumped.

Unfortunately, for privacy reasons I can't show the file.

Comment: You can add **print(openpyxl.__version__)** in your code to print the version of Openpyxl that is being imported

Comment: Will assume this **.load_workboork** is a typo since it would give a different error.  Otherwise probably not much more we can tell you from what you already see, it appears to be a corrupted workbook and even if you 'showed' the sheet it wouldn't make much difference. There are possibly some things you can still try like; It appears you are able to open the workbook, so try to copy 'sheet01' (use Excel Move or Copy sheet) to a new book and try opening that. The used portion of the sheet is large but not impossible to copy the used range manually and paste to a new workbook and try that.

Comment: The exception is pretty clear: the file probably contains some invalid XML. Can't say more without the file, which you can't provide. Good luck!

Comment: I guess it works now after I copied the sheet to another sheet. Thank you for the support.